# How to insert line-break in a card-block area while using pug (web page, HTML)?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I am trying to add a line-break inside `card-block` element **bootstrap v4**
Here is the `pug` code:

```
  #accordion.mb-3(role='tablist', aria-multiselectable='true')
    .card.bg-inverse
      #headingOne.card-header(role='tab')
        strong.mb-0
          a(data-toggle='collapse', data-parent='#accordion', href='#collapseOne', aria-expanded='true', aria-controls='collapseOne')= fa['user log']
      #collapseOne.collapse.show(role='tabpanel', aria-labelledby='headingOne')
        .card-block(style="font-family: monospace; direction: ltr; max-height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll")
          = fa['sample log']
```

And js:

```
fa['sampe log']="how to add a line break here: &#13; <br/> \n \\n \\\n \r \\r &#10; &#13; must be on a new line."
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have Pug insert the content of your variable as-is (instead of escaping HTML code inside of it), use the `!=` operator. This goes for `fa['sample log']` and `fa['user log']`.

```
#accordion.mb-3(role='tablist', aria-multiselectable='true')
  .card.bg-inverse
    #headingOne.card-header(role='tab')
      strong.mb-0
        a(data-toggle='collapse', data-parent='#accordion', href='#collapseOne', aria-expanded='true', aria-controls='collapseOne')!= fa['user log']
      #collapseOne.collapse.show(role='tabpanel', aria-labelledby='headingOne')
        .card-block(style="font-family: monospace; direction: ltr; max-height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll")!= fa['sample log']
```

http://codepen.io/shbelsky/pen/JWqzry